# add one zero if after decimal there is one zero

Tags: php

i have pricing format in which there are number of scenarios that i have to deal with!

my base requirement is after the decimal point there must be two values e.g

```
20.20
100.03
30.34
```

etc , right now the type of pricing i am receiving is

```
30.3
25.52 
100.02
```

etc

now the logic i want to built is that if there are two values after the decimal point it should display them as it is, without any alteration. but if after the decimal point there is one value e.g `30.3` it should add a trailing zero but only upto two digits! this is what i have right now!

```
  <h6> <?php $starting_from = explode('.',$result_1s['price']) ?>
  $<?=round($starting_from[0])?><?=(is_numeric($result_1s['price']) && floor($result_1s['price']) != $result_1s['price']) ? '.'.$starting_from[1] :'.00' ?>
 </h6>
```

how can i modify the above code that it accepts the scenario i explained above. thanks in advance!

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: *"i have pricing format"* -- and you are not using [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) or, at least, [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format the amounts?

Comment: A simple google search would have given you the answer. This question shows no form of research

Comment: i actually googled it went to other functions like floor and round so i kept on working on them. number_format didnt came on top so i though my solutions was in these functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `number_format()` like this:

```
number_format($result_1s['price'], 2, '.', '');
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: `$result_1s` to avoid confusion.

Comment: $result_1s['price'] is the correct var @AbraCadaver thanks for the correction

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri yes its $result_1s['price'] and thanks alot for the help,

Comment: Glad to help you, accept the answer when you can to help other person with your same problem @uneebmeer